# How to get two table information with belongsToMany relationship in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

```
class Movie extends Model {
    public function MoviesWithSites()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\MovieSite','movie_movie_site','movie_id','site_id');
    }
}
```

I tried with above code with that i'm getting only movie site information, but I want movies table result also with it.

Comment: Can you show the query you are using to fetch results?